# Difference between OTP Token and CSRF Token

Tags: security, csrf, one-time-password

I'm searching for **Preventing from URL Forgery**.

Like example below

```
http://www.test.com/tranfer-money.do?value=1000000
```

If I could obtain any victim's session, I could send money what I want much.

I happened to find **CSRF** Technology
and I happend to find **OTP** Technology too.

I think they are exactly the same algorithm.
OTP is like it name says "One Time Password"
and Anti-CSRF is just one of a samples of OTP Architecture"
Isn't it?

The Algorithm is "Server gives to a client an un-predictable token, and Client will request with this token, and Server will verify"

Why I think like this is below Two Reason.

Independent Object issue a token.
At OTP perspective, Hardware or Application issue a unique(unpredictable) token
At Anti-CSRF perspective, WAS Server issue a unique(unpredictable) token
Whatever Issuer they are, The Important thing is The Independent Object from the Client Object issue a token.

The Independent Issuer Object issue a token once at a time.
At OTP, Hardware or Application issue a token just before a user's request for senstive information at Once.
At Anti-CSRF, WAS Server issue a token After user's login at Once too.
(We could make WAS Server issue token everytime. That's upon WAS Server Configuration. If I configure the server to work like this, Can you say that This WAS isn't Anti-CSRF Sever?)

What I want to know is What's the difference between CSRF Token and OTP Token.

Answer (score 1):

OTP (One Time Password) and CSRF (Cross-Site Request Forgery) are different things.

OTP is an authentication mechanism. Some kind of application or hardware token is generating a string you can use to authenticate in a application. Famous example are the RSA tokens which implemented a time-based one time password protocol.

[image: RSA authenticator]

[CSRF](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/352.html) is a weakness of web applications which fail to verify if the user intentionally sent the request. When we speak about CSRF protection, we usually mean protection with anti-CSRF tokens. These tokens are generated by the server and passed by the client in every request that changes the state of the system. All requests without this token are rejected by the server.